# how to select data between two dates in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

i want to select data between two dates, i am using this query but error occurs that "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s)"

```
select * from abc where fmonth between '2015-02' and 2016-03;
```

i also tried this but same error

```
select * from abc where fmonth>=2015-02 and fmonth<=2016-03;
```

Comment: What's the data type of your `fmonth` column?

Comment: character varying

Comment: You should be storing your date information in a date type column, _not_ as varying text.  This will lead to problems for you later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just forgot to quote the second argument in your first attempt:

```
select * from abc where fmonth between '2015-02' and '2016-03';

                                                     ^       ^
```

Comment: This only appears to work because by coincidence the text representing these partial dates sort in order.  But, in general, date information should _never_ be stored as `varchar` in a database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree with your point about storing date information in date columns, but, as long as you maintain your date expressions in a yyyy-mm or yyyy-mm-dd format, in what case would they not sort in order?

Comment: Your comment got me thinking, that this is the reason why the ISO format is year-month-day, because any other order causes logical problems.  Yes, it would work here, but even so the OP would have a hard time taking advantage of the many date functions which Postgres can offer.